# The injection $W^{m, p}(I) \subset W^{m-1, p}(I)$ is compact for $m \ge 2$ and $p \in [1, \infty]$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces

Let $I=(0, 1)$ and $m \ge 2$. Recently, I have proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4784602/brezis-exercise-8-6-5-the-injection-wm-1i-subset-wm-1-1i-is-com) that the injection $W^{m, 1}(I) \subset W^{m-1, 1}(I)$ is compact. I would like to generalize this result, i.e.,

> Let $p \in [1, \infty]$. The injection $W^{m, p}(I) \subset W^{m-1, p}(I)$ is compact.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you have a check on it?

---

We proceed by induction on $m$.

- First, we prove base case $m=2$.

Let $(u_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $W^{2, p} (I)$. Then $(u_n)$ and  $(u'_n)$ are bounded sequences in $W^{1, p} (I)$. I have proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4785172/let-i-be-a-bounded-open-interval-of-mathbb-r-the-injection-w1-pi-s) that the injection $W^{1, p}(I) \subset L^{p}(I)$ is compact. Then there are $u, v \in L^p(I)$ and a subsequence $(n_k)$ such that $u_{n_k} \to u$ and $u'_{n_k} \to v$ in $L^p (I)$. First, we prove that $u' =v$. Indeed,
$$
\int_I u_n \varphi' = - \int_I u_n' \varphi,
\quad \varphi \in C^1_c (I),
$$
and at the limit
$$
\int_I u \varphi' = - \int_I v \varphi,
\quad \varphi \in C^1_c (I).
$$

It follows that $u, u' \in L^p (I)$ and thus $u \in W^{1, p}(I)$. Clearly, $u_{n_k} \to u$ and $u_{n_k}' \to u'$ in $L^p (I)$ imply $u_{n_k} \to u$ in $W^{1, p}(I)$. The claim then follows.

- Assume that the injection $W^{k, p}(I) \subset W^{k-1, p}(I)$ is compact for all $1 \le k \le m$. We will prove that the claim holds for $k=m+1$.

Let $(u_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $W^{m+1, p} (I)$. Then $(u_n)$ and $(u'_n)$ are bounded sequences in $W^{m, p} (I)$. By inductive hypothesis, there are $u, v \in W^{m-1, p}(I)$ and a subsequence $(n_k)$ such that $u_{n_k} \to u$ and $u_{n_k}' \to v$ in $W^{m-1, p}(I)$. First, we prove that $u' =v$. Indeed,
$$
\int_I u_n \varphi' = - \int_I u_n' \varphi,
\quad \varphi \in C^1_c (I),
$$
and at the limit
$$
\int_I u \varphi' = - \int_I v \varphi,
\quad \varphi \in C^1_c (I).
$$

It follows that $u, u' \in W^{m-1, p}(I)$ and thus $u \in W^{m, p}(I)$. Clearly, $u_{n_k} \to u$ and $u_{n_k}' \to u'$ in $W^{m-1, p}(I)$ imply $u_{n_k} \to u$ in $W^{m, p}(I)$. The claim then follows.